# Add new project as an Article in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a joomla project now currently running on.I need to add a separate php project to my joomla project as an article.here what i tried on article;

```
<?php
// You can place PHP like this
include "newprojectfolder/index.php?m=projects&uname=admin&pass=passwd";
?>
```

When I run stand alone new project on that joomla folder it works fine.

```
http://server/Joomlaproject/newprojectfolder/index.php?m=projects&uname=admin&pass=passwd
```

but when it using as a joomla article, it not shows anything...

how can i go through this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sourcerer` to place any code anywhere. This module is very useful and solve TinyMCE editor problems!

view this:
[Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo5OiJzb3VyY2VyZXIiO30=)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla uses the TinyMCE editor which doesn't support writing pure PHP. Therefore you will need to download an extension that allows you to do so. Personally, if it's just PHP you want to use in an article, then I would recommend using [PHP Direct](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470?qh=YToxMzp7aTowO3M6MzoicGhwIjtpOjE7czo0OiJwaHAnIjtpOjI7czo1OiJwaHAncyI7aTozO3M6NjoiZGlyZWN0IjtpOjQ7czo5OiJkaXJlY3Rpb24iO2k6NTtzOjEwOiJkaXJlY3Rpb25zIjtpOjY7czo3OiJkaXJlY3RzIjtpOjc7czoxMToiZGlyZWN0aW9uYWwiO2k6ODtzOjc6IidkaXJlY3QiO2k6OTtzOjk6ImRpcmVjdGluZyI7aToxMDtzOjg6ImRpcmVjdGVkIjtpOjExO3M6MTE6ImRpcmVjdGVtZW50IjtpOjEyO3M6OToiZGlyZWN0aXZlIjt9)

Comment: Thanks Buddy...it not jst a PHP.. :D